# Color of PDF is different when opened in adobe than in preview

Tags: ios, pdf, adobe, uicolor, pdf-conversion

I'm currently working on an app that will generate PDF's that were previously being generated by a different (Windows based app).

I convert a UIView into a PDF, which works 100%. The problem is that when I email that PDF from the ipad to my PC and open it in Adobe the RGB value for all the green in the PDF is different, but not for the other colors. It is very very close to the correct color, it just looks dull compared to the original and Im developing for a client that says it has to be 100% identical.

If I open both PDF's in preview then the RGB value is correct on both but wrong in adobe.

I've tried fudging the values slightly and used every differnent color picker I could find to try get them to look the same, no luck.

The RGB value im trying to get is: R:78 G: 135 B: 38.

What im getting back is: R:62 G: 119 B: 57.

I would post pictures but not a high enough level user yet

If you need any clarification about what ive said please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume your PDF file contains some transparent elements. When Acrobat encounters transparency in a PDF file it switches to CMYK rendering mode thus causing the colors to appear slightly different. There is no off switch for this behavior in Acrobat. The solution is to set an RGB output intent on the PDF file. 
All the above is just an assumption because I have not seen your PDF file.